# Making an function that runs a MC based on a value coming in through an XML socket

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

I have a value coming in through an XML SocketServer, it varies between 0 and 1. 
I want it to play a movieclip every time it changes. It will change every 30 seconds, but like I said, I want it to do an action every time it changes from 0 to 1 and from 1 to 0 again. I've tried something as you can see in the snippet under, but it didn't really work that well. Now my movieclip appears when its 1 (which means for 30 seconds), then disappears for 30 seconds.

P.S. Probably some bracket errors etc in the code, had to copy/paste from different places in Flash, but it works except what I want to happen above.

-- Amundsen

```
import swap.MC;


var xmlSocket:XMLSocket = new XMLSocket();

xmlSocket.connect("172.16.7.3", 3000);
xmlSocket.addEventListener(DataEvent.DATA, onIncomingData);


function onIncomingData(event:DataEvent):void
{   
{
var OSCPACKET:XML = new XML(event.data);
trace(OSCPACKET);

var swap;

for each (var property:XML in OSCPACKET)
{

//Switch Message
swap = property.MESSAGE.(@NAME == "switch_message").ARGUMENT.@VALUE;
trace(swap);
if(swap != laststate)
{
swapmsg.visible = true;
trace("asdasd");
swapmsg.gotoAndStop(2);
laststate = swap;
swapmsg.visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Inside the `if` statement you're setting `swapmsg.visible` to true then to false, that code runs all at once so it will always be not visible (false)